# Group by on multiple columns using Aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had the following Table Structure which is listed below

```
Budhol    COCODE    BEN      OBJ    SPARE2  SPARE1  TASKNO  Value   FieldNameNew
    362103  36      362101  991003  NULL    MA1001  NULL    4516    613030
    362103  36      362101  991003  NULL    MA1001  NULL    9088    613030
    362103  36      362101  991003  NULL    MA1001  NULL    3387    613030
    362103  36      362101  991003  NULL    MA1001  NULL    4026    613030
```

Below is the required Output

```
 Budhol   COCODE    BEN      OBJ    SPARE2  SPARE1  TASKNO  Value   FieldNameNew
    362103  36      362101  991003  NULL    MA1001  NULL    21017   613030
```

i.e The Value should be sumed if all columns are same  i.e. Sum of all Value Column

Below is the query which i have tried but value are not coming properly

```
SELECT B.BEN,
       B.BUDHOL,
       B.COCODE,
       B.FIELDNAMENEW,
       B.OBJ,
       B.SPARE1,
       B.SPARE2,       
       SUM(B.value)as Value into #temp4
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.BEN,
                    A.BUDHOL,
                    A.COCODE,
                    A.FIELDNAMENEW,
                    A.OBJ,
                    A.value,
                    A.SPARE2,
                    A.SPARE1      
    FROM #temp3 A
    LEFT JOIN #temp3 T1 ON A.BEN = t1.BEN
        AND A.BUDHOL = t1.BUDHOL
        AND A.COCODE = t1.COCODE
        AND A.OBJ = t1.OBJ
        AND A.SPARE1 = t1.SPARE1
        AND A.SPARE2 = t1.SPARE2
        AND A.FieldNameNew = t1.FieldNameNew
) B
GROUP BY B.BEN,
         B.BUDHOL,
         B.COCODE,
         B.OBJ,
         B.FIELDNAMENEW,
         B.SPARE1,
         B.SPARE2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you write, a much simpler query will work:

```
SELECT B.BEN, B.BUDHOL, B.COCODE, B.FIELDNAMENEW, B.OBJ, B.SPARE1, B.SPARE2,       
       SUM(B.value) as Value
into #temp4
FROM #temp3 B
GROUP BY B.BEN, B.BUDHOL, B.COCODE, B.FIELDNAMENEW, B.OBJ, B.SPARE1, B.SPARE2;
```